# Why is my MariaDb not adding a column to a large table using the INSTANT algorithm

Tags: mariadb

I have a huge table in a MariaDb (10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic) and I am adding a new column using

```
alter table Appointment add column responsible_organization varchar(256);
```

The existing table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Appointment` (
    `id` VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    `version` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    `repetition_ref` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `type` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(2048) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `end` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `start` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `statuschangedate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deliverystatus` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `reasoncancelled` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `visit_type` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified_db_time` TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(3) ON UPDATE current_timestamp(3),
    `markedasdeleted` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `version`),
    INDEX `FKc4f6e4y3ftaya162pwf7v4uj4` (`deliverystatus`),
    INDEX `FKeuhxsh83rlweegn404penommb` (`reasoncancelled`),
    INDEX `FK5xmurewn61wf4n3of5yx2nsmg` (`visit_type`),
    INDEX `modified_db_time` (`modified_db_time`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK5xmurewn61wf4n3of5yx2nsmg` FOREIGN KEY (`visittype`) REFERENCES `Coding` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKc4f6e4y3ftaya162pwf7v4uj4` FOREIGN KEY (`deliverystatus`) REFERENCES `CodeableConcept` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `FKeuhxsh83rlweegn404penommb` FOREIGN KEY (`reasoncancelled`) REFERENCES `CodingDt` (`id`)
)
;
```

As far as I read the MariaDb documentation it should choose the most efficient algorithm if I don't specify any. I would expect it to use INPLACE at the minimum. But when I run it i can see in the process list that it is running with the state "Copy to tmp table". So this is the COPY algorithm right?

I then tried to force it to use INSTANT as sugested by @o-jones. That gave me this output:

```
MariaDB [mydb]> alter table Appointment add column responsibleorganisation varchar(256), ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
ERROR 1846 (0A000): ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported. Reason: Cannot change column type. Try ALGORITHM=COPY
```

Weird, since I am adding a column.

I am wondering if it has something to do with the table being created on an older version of MariaDb and not having been rebuilt recently. I have found [references to this being an issue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) for tables with old style temporal columns.

The variables `old_alter_table` and `alter_algorithm` both have the value `DEFAULT`

My table has 110+ million rows, so I would have liked to find a way to optimize this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does specifying `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` throw an error? How about `ALGORITHM=INPLACE`?  According to the docs, either of these may take a lot of time, but allow the table to be used while the `ALTER` operation is in progress. That's called "online DDL.` And, even the faster algorithms may need `tmp table` support -- that simply means a copy, possibly in RAM, of some data.

Comment: Just got my DBA to kill the process and try with INSTANT. 

`MariaDB [mydb]> alter table Appointment add column responsibleorganisation varchar(256), ALGORITHM=INSTANT;
ERROR 1846 (0A000): ALGORITHM=INSTANT is not supported. Reason: Cannot change column type. Try ALGORITHM=COPY`

Weird the error does not seem to match the alter statement. I am not changing a column I am adding one.

Comment: Sometimes `ALTER TABLE` thinks it has to change some column's type even when that's not what you specify. Looks like this is one of those times. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this in cases where a database was created in an earlier version of MariaDB. Sometimes the storage format for some columns has changed, but the upgrade did not rewrite all of the data. Instead it waits until certain schema changes are made and then it modifies that underlying data format. In my cases it was because some of the columns were date/datetime and the temporal storage format had changed in 10.3, but many of my tables were still in the old format. Any schema change I made in 10.4 wanted to update the format for all of those columns, which was a pain for tables with many millions of rows.

If you rebuild the table first using "ALTER TABLE tab_name ENGINE = InnoDB;" then the column add would be able to be added "instantly". Although the alter will take as long as the non-instant column add would. However, there are circumstances where doing the processes separately might be advantageous.

In my case I had to do a manual table rebuild because I could not allow the live table to be locked for as long as the rebuild would take. So I wrote a stored procedure to take the table and create a copy of it gradually, and keep the copy up-to-date. The copy process was throttled to avoid putting to much strain on the db and then once the copy was ready I was able to swap the old and new tables quickly with renames so that the down time was measured in seconds instead of hours. Once the new table was in place I was able to do instant ddl operations on it like normal.

Comment: This is the real problem indeed. You can use https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-online-schema-change.html for adding the column and rebuilding the table without locks

Answer (score 4):

MariaDB Server 10.4.10 was released over 2 years ago, in November 2019. Is this repeatable with a more recent version? There have been some fixes to `ALTER TABLE` since then.

If the problem is repeatable with the latest version in the 10.4 series, I would suggest that you file a bug report at https://jira.mariadb.org with a minimal reproducible test case (`CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE` statements).

With a more recent version, the answer could have been that [MDEV-20590](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20590) introduced a way to disable instant operations that involve changing the data file format. `SET GLOBAL innodb_instant_alter_column_allowed=never;` would make `ADD COLUMN` always rebuild the table, like it did before MariaDB Server 10.3.

Comment: Works on [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=fb6349d2e0e6326049906c88bf8c1609) on 10.3.32 and 10.4.22 (after FK typo `visittype` -> `visittype`).